# What are some large, model-rich open source applications?

Tags: c#, java, ruby, domain-driven-design, objective-j

I need to identify a large model-rich open source ruby, c-sharp, objective-j or java applications so that I can target them for a series of projects. Are you guys aware of any that I could use?

Comment: Clarification: Model-rich means that the open source application has a large set of objects that would be classified as "Models" in a MVC-type architecture and as "Domain Models" in the Domain Driven Design methodology.

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by applications.  Do you mean application frameworks are actual implementations of model-rich technologies such as how StackOverflow uses Microsoft ASP.NET MVC?

Comment: How many items constitue a "large set" 10, 100, 1000?

Comment: Applications-->Could be either implementations or frameworks. Both StackOverflow and ASP.NET MVC would be applicable. I just need complex source code that I can refactor.

"Large"-->10 domain objects may be too low. But anything above that is good.

Answer (score 2):

Kigg is a Digg clone written in best of breed ASP.NET MVC with Enterprise Library and a ton of other cutting edge practices.

http://www.codeplex.com/Kigg